# Degree of Hilbert polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes, hilbert-polynomial

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over field $k$,
$\mathscr{L}$ be a very ample line bundle on $X$, and $\mathscr{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$.

There is an unique $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficient polynomial $P(X)\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$,
s.t. for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$,
$$P(n)=\chi(\mathscr{F}\otimes \mathscr{L}^{\otimes n}).$$

What is the degree of the polynomial $P(X)$?
And is it determined by $X, \mathscr{L}, \mathscr{F}$?

Please tell me hint or reference, thanks.

Comment: The degree is equal to the dimension of the support of $\mathcal{F}$. The polynomial is indeed determined by the data of $X$, $\mathcal{L}$, and $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: In case that you want a reference for Sasha's answer, this result can be found in the latter sections of Serre's FAC.